# How to access/retrieve values inside of a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, indexing

I feel like this question should have been asked before but I may be too inexperienced in Python to either (1) locate the answer or (2) understand the answer.

I have a dictionary that contains lists. Each key has three values associated with it inside of a list. Since the values are in a list, I assume that means they are indexed. I know that dictionary keys are unordered and normally values are as well. However, since the values are in a list they should be ordered, correct?

I want to write a for loop that will store the first value within each key to a new list. Or, alternatively, I just want to know how to access values in a dictionary!
I tried the following:
name = dictionary of lists

```
for key, values in name.iteritems():
    xCoord = key[1]
    print xCoord
```

However, I get the error: "IndexError: string index out of range." What would be the way to call/retrieve the first value associated with each key? Thank you!

EDIT: I created the dictionary with the following.

```
inputCSV = r"G:\REDIRECT\GRP\Test\Workspace\GRPNOV16A.csv"
name = {}
with open((inputCSV),'rb') as offenseFile:
    read = csv.DictReader(offenseFile)
    for row in read:
        if row['Defendant'] not in name:
            name[row['Defendant']] = []
        name[row['Defendant']].append((row['X - Offense'],row['Y - Offense'],row['GRP Status']))
    offenseFile.close
```

EDIT 2: For anyone in the future who is inexperienced and needs a similar question answered. The dictionary code above was creating a tuple within a list within the dictionary. As a result, to access the tuple I had to do:

```
for key, values in name.iteritems():
    xCoord = key[0][1]
    print xCoord
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the values are in a list, shouldn't this be more like it?

```
for key, values in name.iteritems():
    xCoord = values[1]
    print xCoord
```

Comment: Works for me. How do you set up your dictionary?

Comment: I have a CSV file that I read with DictReader. I then used a for loop to take only specific rows from the read dictionary and store them into a previously empty dictionary.